# New csproj running on Windows, which target framework?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a new style csproj app which does not need to be cross platform, it will only run on Windows. All my nuget references are .NET Standard libraries.

My target framework is net472. Other than making the app cross platform, are there any benefits in changing this to netcoreapp2.1?

[image]

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

Comment: thanks @junkangli. I had already seen this article but as far as I can see the .NET framework apps they are referring to there are using the old style csproj. I want to know if we get the same performance benefits if choosing netcoreapp2.1 instead of net472 when using the new style csproj for both.

Comment: .NETCore seems to be in never-ending state of not-yet-done.  But not that unusual, it took 6 years for the full framework to get usable.  Just a lot less visible since it wasn't open source back then and initial development was a big secret.  Big changes in version 3 ahead, now also supporting GUI development on Windows.  Could be the proverbial version 3 that Microsoft usually needs to make a product good.

Comment: @jackwild I don't think that article has any relevance to the csproj format. It is comparing between .NET Core and .NET Framework.

Comment: You can also target *both* net472 and netcoreapp2.1 if you really aren't sure which is better or want to compare them easily.

Answer (score 1):

i strongly recommend to use .net core,
.net framework has its known issues and limitations... 
sooner or later .NET framework will be deprecated,
Microsoft is going in the direction of Cross platform framework for the .net ecosystem.
all new features of .net web apis will be introduced to .net core apps,
new libraries will be written for the .net core framework
and most importantly - 
.net core is extremely fast, much much faster than .net framework apps 
you can read more here - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/07/performance-improvements-in-net-core/

few more advantages -
* open source - you can review everything in github, contribute, fork, etc... 
* modular - frequent package updates

hope this helps.

Comment: I am able to use all of the new libraries when targeting net472 as well though. If running as netcoreapp2.1 is indeed faster then that is a reason to choose it instead.

Comment: I would also recommend using .net core because it is lightweight and fast and has a better CLI tooling